# Are there any issues with directly killing Python process?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, kill-process

I work on the Python console interactively. The amount of memory allocated during each of these sessions are usually around 100GB. However, when I try to exit the console, using exit(), it takes ages for the memory to be deallocated and for Python to close properly.

Is it okay to just type `kill -9 python_process_id` since it seems to instantly kill the process? Would there be memory issues related to this?

I work on a server that cannot be freely rebooted.

Comment: also interested in this issue...